# Swift Declare generic type that conforms to a certain protocol in a dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, generics, encode

I am using this function

`public mutating func encodeIfPresent<T>(_ value: T?, forKey key: KeyedEncodingContainer.Key) throws where T : Encodable`

to encode a entity

But my entity contains a dictionary which I also want to use that function to encode

`encodeIfPresent` accept a generic value that conforms to Encodable protocol.

How can I declare my dictionary like `var customFields: [String: Encodable.Type]?` or `var customFields: [String: T] where T : Encodable` to allow the values of the dictionary to be passed to that function?

note: the two methods are just examples which I tried but failed.

Comment: Hopefully conditional conformances will help with this. Dictioanries can be made `Codable` when `Key` and `Value` are both `Codable`

Comment: Could you explain this with some pseudo code?

`container.encodeIfPresent(dic[key], forKey: key)`

I want `dic[key]` to be codable but how can I let the compiler know it?

Comment: Idk enough about Codable to be able to help with this :/

Answer (score 0):

My question is probably duplicated to this one [Store Encodables in a Swift Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358371/store-encodables-in-a-swift-dictionary)

Using its first solution, I made it.

```
struct EncodableValue: Encodable {
    let value: Encodable

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        try value.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}


public struct JWTPayload: Codable {
    var customFields: [String: EncodableValue]?
}

//how to use it
payload.customFields = ["name": EncodableValue(value: "wang"),
                                "isAdmin": EncodableValue(value: true),
                                "age": EncodableValue(value: 125),
                                "height": EncodableValue(value: 181.5)]
```