# JSONEncoder's dateEncodingStrategy not working

Tags: swift, serialization, encodable, jsonencoder

I am trying to serialize a struct to a String using Swift 4's Encodable+JSONEncoder. The object can hold heterogenous values like String, Array, Date, Int etc.

The used approach works fine with the exception of Date.
JSONEncoder's `dateEncodingStrategy` property is not having any effect.

Here is a snippet which reproduces the behaviour in Playground:

```
struct EncodableValue:Encodable {
    var value: Encodable

    init(_ value: Encodable) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        try value.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}

struct Bar: Encodable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let key: String?
    let value: EncodableValue?

    var description: String {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy"
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
        let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(self)
        return String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)!
    }
}

let bar1 = Bar(key: "bar1", value: EncodableValue("12345"))
let bar2 = Bar(key: "bar2", value: EncodableValue(12345))
let bar3 = Bar(key: "bar3", value: EncodableValue(Date()))

print(String(describing: bar1))
print(String(describing: bar2))
print(String(describing: bar3))
```

Output:

```
"{"key":"bar1","value":"12345"}\n"
"{"key":"bar2","value":12345}\n"
"{"key":"bar3","value":539682026.06086397}\n"
```

For bar3 object: I'm expecting something like `"{"key":"bar3","value":"Thurs, 3 Jan 1991"}\n"`, but it returns the date in the default .deferToDate strategy format.

**##EDIT 1##**

So I ran the same code in XCode 9 and it gives the expected output, i.e. correctly formats the date to string.
I'm thinking 9.2 has a minor upgrade to Swift 4 which is breaking this feature. Not sure what to do next.

**##EDIT 2##**

As a temp remedy I'd used the following snippet before changing to @Hamish's approach using a closure.

```
struct EncodableValue:Encodable {
    var value: Encodable

    init(_ value: Encodable) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        if let date = value as? Date {
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encode(date)
        }
        else {
            try value.encode(to: encoder)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have checked your code in Swift 4 Playground and it is giving me this result for bar3 :  {"key":"bar3","value":"Wed, 7 Feb 2018"}

Comment: @ArunKumar - That's curious, because I see precisely the behavior justintime describes when using that `EncodableValue` wrapper.

Comment: @ArunKumar Did you add any additional code or changes to rectify the issue? As for me too, am getting the same response.

Comment: @ShaneD nothing... I just copied your code and pasted in playground

Comment: @ArunKumar What's your XCode version? I was using XCode 9.2, I just ran it XCode 9 and it's working there.

Comment: @ShaneD. I'm using 9.0. Let me update it first then.

Comment: @ArunKumar Just to verify have checked it in Xcode 9 and it seems to be working. The issue is with Xcode 9.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using a custom date encoding strategy, the encoder [intercepts calls](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/fbdcbee7a22ecbb0e4de3dec71c22f7c40bd723a/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L819) to encode a `Date` in a given container and then [applies the custom strategy](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/fbdcbee7a22ecbb0e4de3dec71c22f7c40bd723a/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L721).

However with your `EncodableValue` wrapper, you're not giving the encoder the chance to do this because you're calling directly into the underlying value's `encode(to:)` method. With `Date`, this [will encode the value using its default representation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/fbdcbee7a22ecbb0e4de3dec71c22f7c40bd723a/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/Date.swift#L295), which is as its [`timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780268-timeintervalsincereferencedate).

To fix this, you need to encode the underlying value in a single value container to trigger any custom encoding strategies. The only obstacle to doing this is the fact that [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878), so you cannot call a container's `encode(_:)` method with an `Encodable` argument (as the parameter takes a `<Value : Encodable>`).

One solution to this problem is to define an `Encodable` extension for encoding into a single value container, which you can then use in your wrapper:

```
extension Encodable {
  fileprivate func encode(to container: inout SingleValueEncodingContainer) throws {
    try container.encode(self)
  }
}

struct AnyEncodable : Encodable {

  var value: Encodable

  init(_ value: Encodable) {
    self.value = value
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    try value.encode(to: &container)
  }
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that protocol extension members have an implicit `<Self : P>` placeholder where `P` is the protocol being extended, and the implicit `self` argument is typed as this placeholder (long story short; it allows us to call the `encode(_:)` method with an `Encodable` conforming type).

Another option is to have have a generic initialiser on your wrapper that type erases by storing a closure that does the encoding:

```
struct AnyEncodable : Encodable {

  private let _encodeTo: (Encoder) throws -> Void

  init<Value : Encodable>(_ value: Value) {
    self._encodeTo = { encoder in
      var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
      try container.encode(value)
    }
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    try _encodeTo(encoder)
  }
}
```

In both cases, you can now use this wrapper to encode heterogenous encodables while respecting custom encoding strategies:

```
import Foundation

struct Bar : Encodable, CustomStringConvertible {

  let key: String
  let value: AnyEncodable

  var description: String {

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)

    guard let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(self) else {
      return "Bar(key: \(key as Any), value: \(value as Any))"
    }
    return String(decoding: jsonData, as: UTF8.self)
  }
}

print(Bar(key: "bar1", value: AnyEncodable("12345")))
// {"key":"bar1","value":"12345"}

print(Bar(key: "bar2", value: AnyEncodable(12345)))
// {"key":"bar2","value":12345}

print(Bar(key: "bar3", value: AnyEncodable(Date())))
// {"key":"bar3","value":"Wed, 7 Feb 2018"}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this works since we're using generics to defer the encoding using the value supplied at run time. Because I'd tried
`func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {`
            `var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()`
            `try container.encode(value)`
`}`
Which gave the error 'Cannot invoke 'encode' with an argument list of type '(Encodable)'. Neat, Thanks!

Comment: @justintime Actually just thought of a possibly even neater way to do it using an extension :) And yes, it won't work if you try to call an `encode(_:)` method with an `Encodable` argument because those methods are of the form `<Value : Encodable>(_ value: Value)`, and `Encodable` cannot currently satisfy such a generic placeholder because [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878).

Comment: Why do prefer the extension approach?

Comment: @justintime It's just more flexible; with a constrained generic initialiser you need to know the concrete type at the call-site, but with the wrapper using the extension, you could say things like `let encodables = [1, "hello", Date()].map(AnyEncodable.init)` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the `EncodableValue` wrapper, and use a generic instead:

```
struct Bar<T: Encodable>: Encodable {
    let key: String
    let value: T?

    var json: String {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy"
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
        let data = try! encoder.encode(self)
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    }
}

let bar = Bar(key: "date", value: Date())

print(bar.json)
```

That yields:

```
{"key":"date","value":"Wed, 7 Feb 2018"}
```

Comment: Actually in the bigger picture, I'm using Bar as a property in another struct.
`struct Foo {
    var bars: [Bars]
}`, which is the actual struct I want to serialize.

If I use the generic approach I won't be able to specify the concrete type.
And I'll end up at my old problem you suggested this approach for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358371/store-encodables-in-a-swift-dictionary) . Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: In that case, assuming you can't employ option 2 outlined in that other answer (use strongly typed `struct` rather than heterogenous dictionary or array collections), then you can use Hamish's approach.