# Encode a [String: Encodable] dictionary into JSON using JSONEncoder in Swift 4

Tags: dictionary, swift4, jsonencoder, encodable

I am just curious how can I encode a dictionary with `String` key and `Encodable` value into JSON.

For example:

```
let dict: [String: Encodable] = [
    "Int": 1,
    "Double": 3.14,
    "Bool": false,
    "String": "test"
]
```

The keys in this `dict` are all of type `String`, but the type of the values vary.

However, all of these types are allowed in JSON.

I am wondering if there is a way to use `JSONEncoder` in Swift 4 to encode this `dict` into JSON `Data`.

I do understand there are other ways without using `JSONEncoder` to achieve this, but I am just wondering if `JSONEncoder` is capable of managing this.

The `Dictionary` do have a `func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws` in an extension, but that only applies for constraint `Key: Encodable, Key: Hashable, Value: Encodable`, whereas for our `dict`, it needs constraint `Key: Encodable, Key: Hashable, Value == Encodable`.

Having a `struct` for this will be sufficient to use `JSONEncoder`,

```
struct Test: Encodable {
    let int = 1
    let double = 3.14
    let bool = false
    let string = "test"
}
```

However, I am interested to know if the it can be done without specifying the concrete type but just the `Encodable` protocol.

Comment: You can't do that, `Codable` relies heavily on concrete types. `encode(` is a generic method which expects a **concrete** type which conforms to `Encodable` not the protocol itself.

Answer (score 14):

Just figured out a way to achieve this with a wrapper:

```
struct EncodableWrapper: Encodable {
    let wrapped: Encodable

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        try self.wrapped.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}

let dict: [String: Encodable] = [
    "Int": 1,
    "Double": 3.14,
    "Bool": false,
    "String": "test"
]
let wrappedDict = dict.mapValues(EncodableWrapper.init(wrapped:))
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
let jsonData = try! jsonEncoder.encode(wrappedDict)
let json = String(decoding: jsonData, as: UTF8.self)
print(json)
```

And here is the result:

> {
>     "Double" : 3.1400000000000001,
>     "String" : "test",
>     "Bool" : false,
>     "Int" : 1
>   }

I am still not happy with it. If there are any other approaches, I am more than happy to see it.

Thanks!

## Edit 1 Moving the wrapper into an extension of `JSONEncoder`:

```
extension JSONEncoder {
    private struct EncodableWrapper: Encodable {
        let wrapped: Encodable

        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            try self.wrapped.encode(to: encoder)
        }
    }
    func encode<Key: Encodable>(_ dictionary: [Key: Encodable]) throws -> Data {
        let wrappedDict = dictionary.mapValues(EncodableWrapper.init(wrapped:))
        return try self.encode(wrappedDict)
    }
}

let dict: [String: Encodable] = [
    "Int": 1,
    "Double": 3.14,
    "Bool": false,
    "String": "test"
]

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
let jsonData = try! jsonEncoder.encode(dict)
let json = String(decoding: jsonData, as: UTF8.self)
print(json)
```

Result:

> {
>     "Int" : 1,
>     "Double" : 3.1400000000000001,
>     "Bool" : false,
>     "String" : "test"
>   }

## Edit 2: Take customized strategies into account as per @Hamish 's comments

```
private extension Encodable {
    func encode(to container: inout SingleValueEncodingContainer) throws {
        try container.encode(self)
    }
}

extension JSONEncoder {
    private struct EncodableWrapper: Encodable {
        let wrapped: Encodable

        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try self.wrapped.encode(to: &container)
        }
    }

    func encode<Key: Encodable>(_ dictionary: [Key: Encodable]) throws -> Data {
        let wrappedDict = dictionary.mapValues(EncodableWrapper.init(wrapped:))
        return try self.encode(wrappedDict)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that directly calling into the wrapped value's `encode(to:)` will bypass any encoding strategies for that type – see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664310/2976878 for a wrapper implementation that respects encoding strategies.

Comment: @Hamish Good catch, I've never thought about customized strategies. Love the generic initializer approach by the way.

Comment: @Hamish I tried with the link you posted, it seems the `singleValueContainer` still relies heavily on generic types, and it won't takes a protocol type as an input.

Comment: The `AnyEncodable` wrapper that has the generic `init<Value : Encodable>(_ value: Value)` indeed won't work with arbitrary `Encodable` values – however the first wrapper (that has the `init(_ value: Encodable)`) will work with such values :)

Answer (score 2):

You would need a wrapper since with `Encodable` protocol to know which item is which to be able to encode it easier.

I suggest Use an enum named `JSONValue` which has 5 to 6 cases for all `Int`, `String`, `Double`, `Array`, `Dictionary` cases. then you can write JSONs in a type-safe way.

This [link](https://medium.com/grand-parade/creating-type-safe-json-in-swift-74a612991893) will help too.

This is how I use it:

```
indirect enum JSONValue {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)
    case double(Double)
    case bool(Bool)
    case object([String: JSONValue])
    case array([JSONValue])
    case encoded(Encodable)
}
```

And then make `JSONValue: Encodable` and write encoding code for each case.